# I just want to pass more than 1 parameter to another page. How to do that?

Tags: javascript

I just want to pass more than 1 parameter to another page. How to do that?

```
<input type="submit" value="Add Student" name="submit" 
       onClick="javascript:window.location='editcode.jsp?prid=<%=rs.getString(1)%>&<%=name%>&<%=age%> &<%=sex%> &<%=phone%>';" 
       style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">
```

Comment: Could I see the rest of your HTML?

Comment: what have you tried? what have you done? what is the code you have pasted? alot more information please

Comment: show us the script...I guess it is url encoded string

Comment: We can't help you, when you only provide us with so less detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only specified the parameter name for `prid`, all the others are only values.

Your output would look something like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add Student" name="submit" 
    onClick="javascript:window.location='editcode.jsp?
    prid=some-value&some-value&some-value&some-value&some-value';
    style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;">
```

Which will present empty parameters with names that are the `values` you want to set them to -- not their proper names -- for the last 4 parameters.

I think you want to change your code to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Add Student" name="submit" 
   onClick="javascript:window.location='editcode.jsp?
   prid=<%=rs.getString(1)%>
   &name=<%=name%>
   &age=<%=age%> 
   &sex=<%=sex%> 
   &phone=<%=phone%>';" 
   style="background-color:#49743D;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;">
```